# interchanging limit and exterior derivative to prove $L_X(df) = d(L_Xf)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $f: M \to \Bbb{R}$ a smooth function and let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$, with flow $(t,p) \mapsto\phi(t,p) \equiv \phi_t(p)$. I'm trying to prove that the Lie derivative commutes with exterior derivative, i.e
\begin{align}
L_X(df) = d(L_Xf)
\end{align}

The definition of Lie derivative I'm working with is that for any tensor field $T$ on $M$,
\begin{align}
L_XT &:= \dfrac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \phi_t^*T
\end{align}

For my particular case where $T=df$, by using the properties of $d$, we have that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\phi_t^*(df) - \phi_0^*(df)}{t} &= d \left( \dfrac{\phi_t^*f - f}{t} \right)
\end{align}
I'd now like to take the limit $t \to 0$ on both sides. However, if on the RHS I can justify why
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0}d \left( \dfrac{\phi_t^*f - f}{t} \right) = d \left( \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\phi_t^*f - f}{t} \right)
\end{align}
then of course my proof will be complete. But this is where I'm having trouble.

---

I've tried the following. For any $p \in M$, we have that
\begin{align}
(\phi_t^*f)(p) &= (f \circ \phi)(t,p) \\
&= f(p) + t \dfrac{\partial(f  \circ \phi)}{\partial t} \bigg|_{(0,p)} + R_t(p) \\
&= f(p) + t (L_Xf)(p) + R_t(p)
\end{align}
for some smooth $(t,p) \mapsto R_t(p)$ which satisfies $\lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{R_t(p)}{t} = 0$

But then I realized this doesn't simplify much because
\begin{align}
d \left( \dfrac{\phi_t^*f - f}{t} \right) &= d(L_Xf) + d \left( \dfrac{R_t}{t} \right)
\end{align}
so I still have to justify why interchanging the limit $t \to 0$ with the exterior derivative on second term is valid.

I also tried to write it out in coordinates, and it seems to have something to do with equality of mixed partials, but I just can't figure out how (if that is even the case). SO, any help is appreciated in justifying the exchange of limits and $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's precisely equality of mixed partials. Working in local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on $M$, let's set $F(x,t) = f(\phi_t(x)) = (\phi_t^*f)(x)$. Then $F$ is smooth and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0}.$$
Therefore
$$\sum \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^i}dx^i = \sum \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\Big|_{t=0} dx^i.$$
This means that $\mathscr L_X(df) = d(\mathscr L_Xf)$, as desired.

Comment: I see, I partly got confused about where where each derivative was being evaluated. I also obtained the last term you wrote down, but didn't realize that the last term you wrote down is precisely $d(\mathscr{L}_Xf)$... but of course now it is obvious. Thanks for the clarification.